# Multiple Emacs servers

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to setup multiple Emacs servers, following instructions at http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html

The problem is that M-x set-variable  server-name  foo  doesn't seem to have an effect on the server name after starting, the server is still registered with default name "server". Also, I don't see an option for server name in daemon mode. Any ideas what's wrong?

I'm using version GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars) of 2011-06-07

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `server-name` before calling `server-start`. With daemon mode, you can use `--daemon=SERVERNAME`. See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html#Initial-Options